# Detecting isRound or isSquare for android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm sending notification to a wearable from a handheld and then displaying background images on cards without text.  I'd like to optimize the images for round and square wearables without creating a standalone app and wearable activities.

How would I send a message to the wearable asking what size it is and if it's round or square?  I know how to send messages, I'm just looking for the api to look up if it's round or square.

From the following sample, you can see how you would detect this in an activity, but I'd like to detect this in a background service since I don't want to create a standalone wearable app.
https://github.com/mauimauer/AndroidWearable-Samples/blob/8287982332b82cada7bf68a6c5aa88df1bbbcbbe/GridViewPager/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/gridviewpager/MainActivity.java

My other question shows how to detect if there is a wearable paired, but it only returns node name and node id, no other useful information about the actual wearable.
[How to detect if android device is paired with android wear watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877170/how-to-detect-if-android-device-is-paired-with-android-wear-watch)

Comment: "... I don't want ot create a standalone wearable app ...." This is where you may be going wrong ... the UX required for a useful wearable app is much different from that for a tablet / "smartphone" / web etc.  You should consider sharing what code you need among your apps .. but design the UX (interaction and space) for wearable differently!

Comment: I'm just doing simple push notifications with background images.  Creating a standalone app for extending push notifications seems like overkill.  I'm still creating wearable optimized images, I just need to optimize them further for either a circle or square interface.

Comment: You're going to need to either create a separate wearable app, or not take this approach to the problem you're trying to solve. Why exactly do you need to know if it's round or square? Can't you just provide a high-res enough image at the appropriate size?

Comment: I'm generating images that include a bar chart.  I need to know if I'm on a round or square device so that I can have the chart take up all available space.  Otherwise the square device has a bunch of padding to account for the round device.

Answer (score 3):

The official way to determine round vs square is to use the WatchInsets class, and the isRound() method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.html#isRound()

There is a sample named GridViewPager included in the Android SDK Manager for API 20 that shows how to use the isRound() method.

For the rest of your question ... you will need to implement an app that runs on the watch, that would perform this query for you. You can then send a message to the watch, it performs the query, and then send a message back to the phone, for whatever else it is you want to do.

If you look at the DataLayer sample (also in the same place as GridViewPager) it shows how to detect the connection status of the wearable to the phone.

Comment: I have the standalone app working and messages between the app and phone working.  I'm not exactly sure how to perform the query you are talking about.  Could you give an example?

Comment: When I mentioned the query, I was talking about calling isRound(). It sounds like you need the phone to find out what the shape of the display is. You could modify the DataLayer sample so that when a message is sent from the wearable to the phone, it could add a value to represent the result of the isRound() call.

Answer (score 2):

Unofficial way - but for me it was way way easier.
https://github.com/tajchert/ShapeWear

Just copy ShapeWear.java class, and subscribe to screen shape detection event `setOnShapeChangeListener()` or call method `ShapeWear.isRound()` (can throw error is shape is not yet determined) or `ShapeWear. getShape()` - which can result in `ShapeWear.SHAPE_UNSURE` in same situation.

Answer (score 1):

override this method in ur Engine class that extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine

```
    @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);

        Log.d(TAG, "onApplyWindowInsets");
        if (insets.isRound()) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Round");

        } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Square");

        }
    }
```