# Android Wear: CapabilityApi times out, doesn't return capabilities

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

I'm trying to use a new CapabilityApi introduced in play services 7.3 to learn about the capabilities of my android wear device(Asus Zenwatch). I've checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24877170/1204377) and can confirm that Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(...) approach does work to get a list of connected nodes and I do see the watch in the list. This is the code I'm running in an app on my phone to query capabilities of connected wear devices:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();

PendingResult<CapabilityApi.GetAllCapabilitiesResult> result = 
    Wearable.CapabilityApi.getAllCapabilities(mGoogleApiClient, CapabilityApi.FILTER_ALL);

Map<String, CapabilityInfo> capabilities = result.await().getAllCapabilities();
```

**context** in this case is an activity. This call is happening on a non-ui thread, so calling await() is safe. I inserted a breakpoint on the last line, but when I hit it and step over it, the debugger never returns, as if the method runs forever and never returns. If I replace **await()** with **await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)**, then it just times out after 10 seconds and **capabilities** is assigned null. The behavior is the same on a phone paired with android wear, or not paired with it, or on an emulator.

Am I missing something? What's the correct way to use CapabilityApi and get a list of available capabilities and not have it time out?

**EDIT 1:**

With help of @ianhanniballake I came up with this code that doesn't hang, but returns the result very quickly:

```
ConnectionResult connectionResult = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
if (connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
    PendingResult<CapabilityApi.GetAllCapabilitiesResult> result =
                    Wearable.CapabilityApi.getAllCapabilities(mGoogleApiClient, CapabilityApi.FILTER_ALL);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Map<String, CapabilityInfo> capabilities =
                    result.await().getAllCapabilities();
    return capabilities != null && !capabilities.isEmpty();
} else {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    return false;
}
```

However, when I run this code on a phone that is paired with Android smart watch, **capabilities** ends up being either an empty list, or null. Is this the expected result? I thought I was supposed to get a list of my smart watch's capabilities. Or is this code supposed to be ran on the watch itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect your `GoogleApiClient`. Consider using [blockingConnect()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#blockingConnect()) as you are on a background thread, then checking the resulting [ConnectionResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) to ensure the connection succeeded.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, it did work! But I have a follow-up question, capabilities still ends up being null or an empty list on a phone paired with Android wear device. I updated the question.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the Capabilities Api: these are capabilities defined *by your app* to allow you to distinguish between nodes. Check out the [sending messages training](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) for an example of using the API.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was suspecting that I misunderstood the concept. Thanks!