# Is NodeApi specific to Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client, android-wear-data-api

I want to detect the connected Android Wear device in my app. I [found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877170/how-to-detect-if-android-device-is-paired-with-android-wear-watch) using [NodeApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi). But the documentation doesn't say anything about that is it specific to Android Wear or not:

> Exposes an API for to learn about local or connected Nodes.
>
> Node events are delivered to all applications on a device.

What is a Node here? Is it any device that connected over bluetooth or specific Android Wear device connected over bluetooth? I want to detect if the device connected is Android Wear device and get its display name. Any reference about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NodeApi is for Android Wear, but it is an API that can be used on the device side.

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = 
    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( mApiClient ).await();
```

Then for each node within nodes, you can call `getDisplayName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that was my silly mistake. I found the package name : `com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi`. So, yes; NodeApi is only for Android Wear.