# Detecting connected/disconnected android wear device

Tags: wear-os

I am currently doing an android wear app that has 2 modes : connected (paired with the mobile phone) and disconnected. I looked at this thread ([How to detect if android device is paired with android wear watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877170/how-to-detect-if-android-device-is-paired-with-android-wear-watch)). I added listeners to detect when a node is found.

```
@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED");          
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
    Log.d(TAG, "PEER DISCONNECTED");
}
```

There are the following cases : 
- If the mobile app is launched, the wear app will detect a node and go into the connected mode.
- If the mobile app is killed, it sends a message before getting destroyed to the watch and the watch goes into disconnected mode.
- If the bluetooth connection is lost, the wear app goes into disconnected mode.

I am a bit lost on the way of doing this. How can I know if the correct node is paired? (the mobile that contains the app)?

EDIT :

Here is the code I use with the capabilities :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){


    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.s_instance.getApplicationContext(), "mApiClient : " + mApiClient, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (mApiClient != null && !(mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting()))
        mApiClient.connect();

    setupNode();

    Wearable.CapabilityApi.addCapabilityListener(
            mApiClient,
            capabilityListener,
            CAPABILITY_NAME);

    //Listener to check connection with the mobile (bluetooth enabled/disabled and device detected)
    super.onCreate();
}

private void setupNode() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mApiClient != null && !(mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting()))
                mApiClient.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(
                    mApiClient, CAPABILITY_NAME,
                    CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult result) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.s_instance.getApplicationContext(), "TRYING TO GET NODE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (result.getCapability() == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.s_instance.getApplicationContext(), "WE DETECTED NO CAPABILITY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.s_instance.getApplicationContext(), "WE DETECTED A CAPABILITY : " + result.getCapability(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    updateCapability(result.getCapability());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using [CapabilitApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi)? If your app on the mobile provides a certain capability that you are interested in, you can use these apis to query for the nodes (connected and nearby) that provide that capability. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I didn't know about that API, I'll have to get a closer look. I guess a capability is like an id?

Comment: You should look at that more like broadcasting what "service" your app is providing and others can search for that type of "service" provider.

Comment: I looked at a sample given by google here (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FindMyPhone/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/findphone/DisconnectListenerService.java) but there is a case that I can't understand how to detect : I kill the mobile app, how can I detect that case on the wear side?

Comment: When your mobile app is killed, all the capabilities that it was providing should go away and you should be notified in onCapabilityChanged() (if you have registered a listener).

Comment: what do you mean by it never passes in? If your app is not running on the mobile, are you claiming that the capability that it is supposed to provide is still available?

Comment: I added a log in the listener and when I kill the app, I don't display the log showing the the capability is removed. I'll edit my question and post a part of my code

Comment: How do you kill your app?

Comment: I kill my activity and unregister the services. But I could be doing something wrong there, and that's where the problem would come from : the app is still alive

Comment: There is also something I don't understand : if I launch my wear app, everything works fine, but if I kill it and launch it fast again, I don't detect the capabilities : it's like I don't give enough time to connect to the google apis, but I did a blockingconnect for 100 ms, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: If you do a blockingConnect(), you can get the result of that to see if you got connected after the timeout or not; that is why I usually prefer to not do a blockingConnect and instead rely on onConnected() callback. Secondly, you are calling "connect()" in your onCreate() as well, so if you are going to do a blocking one, why are you calling connect() in the onCreate()? Thirdly, I don't see you "disconnecting" yourself when your app exits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93090/discussion-between-krakig-and-ali-naddaf).