# Start watch face configuration activity from app

Tags: android, wear-os

I have built a configuration activity for a watch face. Android wear shows and starts the configuration activity fine.

Is it possible to start the configuration activity from a companion app?

I created an activity, but wasn't able to pass the EXTRA_PEER_ID which the Android Wear activity seems to be passing when starting the configuration activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with help from [How to detect if android device is paired with android wear watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877170/how-to-detect-if-android-device-is-paired-with-android-wear-watch)
The EXTRA_PEER_ID is just the `nodeId` of the connected wear device which can be retrieved with the code below.

You can then use `Intent.putExtra(WatchFaceCompanion.EXTRA_PEER_ID, nodeId);` and pass the id via an intent and start the configuration activity.

Code:

```
private GoogleApiClient client;
private static final long CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS = 1000;

public void checkIfWearableConnected() {

    retrieveDeviceNode(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void success(String nodeId) {
            Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "There was at least one wearable found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "There are no wearables found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
    if (client == null)
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();
    return client;
}

private interface Callback {
    void success(final String nodeId);
    void failed(final String message);
}

private void retrieveDeviceNode(final Callback callback) {
    final GoogleApiClient client = getGoogleApiClient(this);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            client.blockingConnect(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result =
                    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).await();
            List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
            if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                String nodeId = nodes.get(0).getId();
                callback.success(nodeId);
            } else {
                callback.failed("no wearables found");
            }
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to send data to wearable through my own activity. If someone will continue using `client` object, don't `client.disconnect()` after get the node id.