# getConnetedNodes hits timeout without Wear app installed

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

In trying to detect whether our Android app's user has a Wear device paired with their phone, we call

```
// Call Wear API to see whether a device is connected
... nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(client).await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
return nodes.getNodes().size() > 0;
```

We have just noticed that, in some cases, this blocks for the full 20 seconds before returning an empty node collection, rather than returning immediately as we are used to. (If we take out the timeout and call asynchronously, it seems to never resolve.)

On further inspection, we have found that it seems to happen when the user does not even have the Wear app installed on their prone. Thus we are prefixing the above line with something like

```
// Check if the Wear app is installed as we can't have a watch without it
try
{
    getPackageManager()
        .getPackageInfo("com.google.android.wearable.app", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

This seems sufficient for our purposes, but it also seems horrible:

- We're using try/catch for non-exceptional behaviour
- The interaction between the Wear app and the Wear API seems undocumented

Is there a more sensible way to check whether a Wear device is connected without worrying about the timeout?

Comment: Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877170/how-to-detect-if-android-device-is-paired-with-android-wear-watch), I think it might help.

Comment: I'm using two of the three techniques discussed there, and I'm not sure the third (bluetooth check) is going to fly.

Comment: Most of the answers in that thread are obsolete; the Node API is deprecated.

Comment: @String [Bits of it are](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi) but `getConnectedNodes` seems not to be.