# From Wear app check if Wear device is connected to Handheld device, 2021

Tags: android, wear-os

From a Wear app I'm trying to constantly check if the Wear device is connected to the Handheld device. We can do that through `Wearable.getNodeClient(context).connectedNodes`. Is there any way to add a listener to that data? Also, is there any way to make sure any of these nodes is a Handheld device?

Using the CapabilityClient we can know if the app is installed by adding a capability to the `wear.xml` file in the Handheld app. I am not looking to check that.

I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877170/how-to-detect-if-android-device-is-paired-with-android-wear-watch) question, but it doesn't answer mine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add an `ACTION_CAPABILITY_CHANGED` action to the manifest and then add a [CapabilityClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityClient) listener. Within your `OnCapabilityChangedListener` you can then check `getNodes()` from the passed in `CapabilityInfo` to obtain an updated list of available modes. As for checking if it's a handheld or a watch, you should already have different capability strings for each, so you can simply filter the node set on the one you've set for the handheld.