# Is there way to know Bluetooth connection status to a device during app startup in android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-broadcast

I have a use case where I want to know whether my Bluetooth is connected to any other device during my app startup time. Like I know we have a broadcast receiver to listen to connectivity status changes but specifically, I want to know at the app starting time whether it is connected to any other device or not.
More specifically I have a wearOS watch and I'm running the app overwatch so I want to check whether it's connected to the phone or not

Comment: My company makes a Bluetooth serial dongle that connects to a personal role radio that can be controlled by Android devices via its serial interface. The Android device can track state changes between the Bluetooth dongle and itself by connecting to it, but not between the dongle and the radio. The Android code must include a remote protocol to communicate with the radio in order to detect radio connection state in a request-response approach. If the Android app does not receive a radio response, it means the radio connection is not successful (so the remote icon can be disabled).

Comment: As a result, Google must provide an API to communicate with the Wear OS device in order to detect a successful connection. It seems it has the API...refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877170/how-to-detect-if-android-device-is-paired-with-android-wear-watch

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : There is no direct way to find out the connected devices for non-system apps. But there is a hack to figure out the connected devices, with less guarantee.

System apps such as Android settings use `BluetoothDevice.isConnected()` API to get the current connection status of paired/bonded devices. This system API can't be used by non-system apps.

Here is how a non-system app can figure out connected device:

0. Make sure all required [bluetooth permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) are mentioned in manifest and granted.
1. Get list of paired/bonded devices by calling `BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()`
2. Now we will try to establish socket connection to each device via [RFCOMM socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)) .
3. If the API throws any error, then most probably the devices aren't connected, or can't connect.
4. Now if the socket connection is established then there is a chance the devices are connected. To verify if device is connected by calling [isConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket#isConnected()) on the socket connection.

This way you can identify all the connected devices. Now this is a resource intensive task. I would recommend to do it once at the beginning. Post that until your app is active listen to [ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) and [ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED) broadcasts.